# The cross entropy of Pólya Gamma distribution

Tags: polya-urn-model, polya-counting-theory

Is there analytical solution for computing the cross entropy of Pólya Gamma distribution? For example,

$$\int_{\omega} P_{PG}(\omega|1,c)*\log P_{PG}(\omega|1,0)d\omega$$